# Como "me livrar" do espaço vertical entre divs?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de deixar cada pedaço do meu website grudado um ao outro, cada um em uma cor diferente. Porém não consigo me livrar do espaço em branco que permanecem entre as divs. Já tentei remover o espaço do código e aplicar font-size:0 (dicas que vi na internet) mas não adiantou. As duas divs de cores de fundo distintas deveriam estar grudadas uma a outra, aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/9byzo8cu/

Comment: A tag h2 e a classe "text" estão com margens setadas, por isso o espaço em branco entre as divs. Da uma organizada lá na sua folha de estilos.

Exemplo com as divs coladas: https://jsfiddle.net/9byzo8cu/3/

Comment: Obrigado. Achava que pela <h2> estar dentro da div "fundo1", apenas os estilos dessa div importavam !

Comment: O h2 possui essa margem por padrão, você precisa sobrescrever os valores ou simplesmente colocar um reset no começo do seu css.

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoKawanaka, direto e com informações valiosas para mim ! Obrigado =]

Comment: Sem problemas =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São as tags `p` e `h2` que estão causando o problema. Se você adicionar o código abaixo em seu [css](/questions/tagged/css), observará que os espaços serão removidos.

```
p, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta usar um reset nos teus projetos algo como isso:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

resolveria teu problema.
Caso você queira saber mais sobre css-resets, leia este artigo: http://tableless.com.br/css-reset/